# Check a checkbox on keypress on a label

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following on angular

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test"/>
<label for="test">Testing</label>
```

I'm trying to set a checkbox checked when i press **enter** on a **label** while using the tab and the focus is on the label

```
<input type="checkbox" id="test"/>
<label for="test" ng-click="setCheckBox($event)">Testing</label>
```

so far i tried using ng-click, ng-keydown or even onclick and nothing happens.  i was hoping to achieve this using just css. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#mycheckbox').keypress(function(event) {
                var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

                if (keycode == 13) {
                    clickCheckBox(this);
                }   
                event.stopPropagation();
            });             
        });

        function clickCheckBox(box){

                var $box = $(box); 
                    $box.prop('checked',!$box.prop('checked')); 

        }
```

HTML

```
<input type='checkbox' id='mycheckbox'>dev</input>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/c2S5d/23/